# GZipStream create a invalid charaset

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, gzip

I have a simple function to create a gzip file. This function work fine and pass the unit test. Then I hosted the generated filed at amazon s3.

But it produce some invalid character when the input value contain a unicode character.

eg.アームバンド & ケース > 9ÎvøS‰

```
public static void CompressStringToFile(string fileName, string value)
{

    // Use GZipStream to write compressed bytes to target file.
    using (FileStream f2 = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
    using (GZipStream gz = new GZipStream(f2,CompressionMode.Compress, false))
    {
        byte[] b = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value);
        gz.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
        gz.Flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: When/where do you detect those invalid chars? Is the rest of the text OK?

Comment: I see it in chrome developer Tools. It is fixed. Please refer my comment on answer. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of GZip compression isn't *meant* to be text. It's effectively arbitrary binary content, which you should only use to *decompress* it to the original binary content... which in your case is UTF-16-encoded text. You shouldn't expect to be able to read the gzip file as a text file.

GZip itself doesn't interpret the (binary) data that it's given - it just compresses it, so it can be faithfully decompressed later on. GZip couldn't care less whether it's text, an image, a sound file, whatever: it just does the best it can to compress it.

Comment: Thx. I got it by encode the text in utf-8 and specifing the Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8 in response

Comment: @Kuroro: If this is for a web response, why don't you just let the layer above (e.g. IIS) perform the compression? There's no reason for you to do it at the application level.

Comment: The pre-gzip file will host in amazon cloudfront. As cloudfront doesn't support gzip on the fly so I need to pre-process it.